# Wordpress: What are "permalinks" besides mod_rewrite rules?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I know that permalinks involve rewrite rules and they are somehow updated by Dashboard > Settings > Save changes. Sometimes this must be "refreshed" when you add plugins the create new re-write rules... but usually the .htaccess file doesn't change. So what is that button actually doing?

I know it tries to re-write the .htaccess file (if it has sufficient permissions on the server), but does it do something else? Is there a cache or database record somewhere as well?

For reference, here's [the codex page for permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks). (It only talks about .htaccess)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such button in WP core. Are you referring to a plugin?

Comment: There is. It's in Settings > Permalinks > Save changes. I'll update the question to clarify the exact name of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also tells WordPress to write the form values to the options table for the following options:

- `permalink_structure`
- `category_base`
- `tag_base`

The default permalink structures denoted by radio buttons simply have the structure pre-formatted for the user, so the **Day and name** option for example is simply written into the database as

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

The **Default** option is written into the database as an empty string to indicate not to use pretty permalinks.

Comment: I knew there was more to it! Thanks!